# How to fit exogenous + GARCH Model In Python?

Tags: time-series, garch, econometrics, estimation, python

I am studying a textbook of statistics / econometrics, using Python for my computational needs. I have encountered GARCH models and my understanding is that this is a commonly used model.
In an exercise, I need to fit a time series to some exogenous variables, and allow for GARCH effects. I looked but found no package in Python to do it. I found [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arch/3.0) but I think it only supports 1 exogenous variable - I have a bunch of them. This surprises me because I thought this would be something that some quants do every other day... Have I been looking in the wrong places?

Thank you very much

Comment: You're right: Python doesn't have a lat of packages for Time Series Analysis. There's arch and statsmodels, and that's about it. You might want to look at R, which has better support for time series.

Answer (score 2):

It is an old thread. Just pointing out that capability is available in ARCH package now for the benefit of future readers.
https://pypi.org/project/arch/

Volatility models
ARCH
GARCH
TARCH
EGARCH
EWMA/RiskMetrics